# Annotations dont show title/subtitle on MapKit , iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, annotations, mapkit

I am parsing some data with some points of interests and trying to show them on map using the MapKit framework. 
I created a custom class for my objects on the map which i call MyLocation.

MyLocation.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MyLocation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    NSString *_name;
    NSString *_address;
    NSInteger _eventId;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D _coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;

}

@property (nonatomic , copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic , copy) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger eventId;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)name address:(NSString*)address coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

@end
```

MyLocation.m:

```
#import "MyLocation.h"

@implementation MyLocation
@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize eventId=_eventId;
@synthesize address = _address;
@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;
@synthesize title;
@synthesize subtitle;



- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)name address:(NSString*)address coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _name= [name copy];
        _address = [address copy];
        _coordinate = coordinate;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)title {
    if ([_name isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        NSLog(@"11111111");
        return @"Unknown charge";
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"222222");
        return _name;

    }
}

- (NSString *)subtitle {
    NSLog(@"HAHAHAHAA");
    return _address;
}

@end
```

Then on my viewController i do this :

```
//showing on map the points of interests that are stored on "eventList"
int i=0;
for (parsedItem *event in self.eventsList) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.latitude = event.latitude;
    coordinate.longitude = event.longitude;
    if(i==0){
        //numbers show map zoom. 500,500 = map stretches 500 meters to the North and the South of current location
        MKCoordinateRegion region =
        MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (coordinate,1000,1000);
        [mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
    }
    MyLocation *eventAnnotation = [[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:event.typeEvent address:event.titleEvent coordinate:coordinate] ;        
    eventAnnotation.name = event.typeEvent;
    eventAnnotation.address = event.titleEvent;
    eventAnnotation.eventId = i;
    i++;        
    [mapView addAnnotation:eventAnnotation];
}
```

Later i use some more code to give images to the annotations and everything appears on the map BUT if i click on the annotations i dont see the window with the title and the subtitle. I only see the annotations but without the extra information that i should get when i click on them.

I guess theres something wrong with this line of code :

```
MyLocation *eventAnnotation = [[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:event.typeEvent address:event.titleEvent coordinate:coordinate] ;
```

Any ideas?

### EDIT

just to add that i also use this function:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView2 viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";   
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyLocation class]]) {
        NSLog(@"I got into the class!!!");
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        MyLocation *eventAnnotation=annotation;


        if ([eventAnnotation.address isEqualToString: @"Culture_07/02/2012"]) {
            NSLog(@"Mphkeeee");
            annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"culture.png"];
            //annotation.title = @"Holla!";
        } else if ([eventAnnotation.address isEqualToString: @"Sports_06/29/2012"]) {
            annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sports.png"];
        } else if ([eventAnnotation.address isEqualToString: @"Accident_06/29/2012"]) {
            annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"accident.png"];
        } else if ([eventAnnotation.address isEqualToString: @"Problem_06/29/2012"]) {
            annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"problem.png"];
        } else if ([eventAnnotation.address isEqualToString: @"Traffic_07/02/2012"]) {
            annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"traffic.png"];
        } else if ([eventAnnotation.address isEqualToString: @"Music_06/29/2012"]) {
            annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"music.png"];
        } 

        return annotationView;

    }

    return nil;    
}
```

Comment: What class is MyLocation subclass of? i don't see where you set the subtitle property of the annotation as well

Comment: @interface MyLocation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> , the last line of code doesnt set the title , subtitle and coordinates??

Comment: it sets the custom properties coordinate, address and name. it doesn't set the subtitle of MKAnnotationView.

Comment: But i took this code from another project (from a friend developer) and to his project works. Maybe he does smth else in his code that i am missing but i would swear thats the only think he does with the map.. Do you have any idea how i could add a title and a subtitle? Its not only the subtitle! when i press on the icon nothing happens! Shouldnt be a pop-up window even with blank information??

Comment: Try nslogging eventAnnotation.subtitle and write here the log.

Comment: plz also look to my edited answer , thats the last part of code i am using , maybe i am missing smth there

Comment: I just nslogged the eventAnnotation.subtitle and it returns the address! So the subtitle is passed correctly.. Why doesnt it work?

Comment: In MyLocation.m, in the getter method for title, comment out all the code in the method and put this instead: `return @"hello";`.  Run that and see if the callout appears.

Comment: OMG... it worked... i just changed the title and left the subtitle as it was and it worked.. and i just realized why it didnt work.. the xml file that i was parsing had an error in the server and returned me an empty title so it was like i had no title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom getter method for the `title` and `subtitle` instead of setting those properties explicitly is fine with the map view.

The reason your callouts are not showing is because `title` (which is returning `_name` -- which is set to `event.typeEvent`) is returning a `nil` or empty string.

Your getter method is checking if `_name` is of type `NSNull` but it could be an `NSString` and still be `nil` or an empty string.

When `title` is `nil` or an empty string, the annotation will not display the callout (even if `canShowCallout` is set to `YES` and even if `subtitle` is returning a non-empty value).

So it's most likely that `typeEvent` is `nil` or an empty string.

Comment: u are completely right. i found that out when a guy in a comment above suggested to nslog the "title" value and actually saw it was nill. Very smart observation though , thank you very much for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you never actually set the `title` or `subtitle` attributes. In the place where you set up your title, do something like this:

```
eventAnnotation.title = event.typeEvent;
eventAnnotation.subtitle = event.titleEvent;
```

and make sure you have the `title` and `subtitle` properties set up in the `.h` file.

**Edit:** Here's the header for one of my annotations:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapmarkAnnotation : NSObject
<MKAnnotation>
{
    NSString *title;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@end
```

Comment: Shouldnt they be passed with this line of code : MyLocation *eventAnnotation = [[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:event.typeEvent address:event.titleEvent coordinate:coordinate] ;        

Cause when i try to nslog eventAnnotation.subtitle and eventAnnotation.title i get back the subtitle and the title! 

Also what do you mean to set the title and subtitle on the .h file? You can see on the .m file the 2 functions... At the .h file is just the header for these functons..

Comment: If it try to do this : eventAnnotation.title = event.typeEvent; 
   i get this error:   
assigning to property with "readonly" attribute not allowed!

Comment: Have you tried setting an `NSLog` inside the `title` method to see if it's ever called?

Comment: It's readonly because you probably haven't set up the property, and it has no setter defined.

Comment: i just did on both title , subtitle methods and they r both called

Comment: You can define a setter by using a @property.

Comment: OK, you need to set up @properties for `title` and `subtitle` in the `.h` file. Copy the ones in my answer, add `@synthesize` in the `.m` and you should be good.

Comment: I just did , it doesnt work :( look my editted question to see the changes i made on the mylocation.h/m files , in case i did smth wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKAnnotation/title) doc. you need to set title and subtitle of an annotation object yourself. not some other property like _address instead. There is also 2 sample projects in that doc, check them out as well.

Comment: i just checked the sample codes. In the title , subtitle functions they return a string. smth like return @"mpla mpla"; i return a variable called _address. Whats the problem with that? i dont understand...