# Hide title and subtitle fields in MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I would like to display a callout view with only right and left callout accessories, hiding the middle section that shows the subtitle and title.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310224/annotations-dont-show-title-subtitle-on-mapkit-ios) asks the question in objective C, and the answer explains that just setting the title and subtitle to the empty string or NIL will not work since the callout view will not be shown if these fields don't have a value. I encountered the same error.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847133/how-can-i-customize-the-title-subtitle-font-in-callout-from-mkannotationview-or) asks this question in swift, but recieved no answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all you can do is add a detail view and left and right accessory views to the callout. I found a post online that goes into detail about creating a completely custom callout accessory view. It tells the system not to display a callout view, and then adds the custom callout view as a subview of the annotation view.

See this link: [**How To Completely Customise Your Map Annotations Callout Views**](http://sweettutos.com/2016/03/16/how-to-completely-customise-your-map-annotations-callout-views/)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I set the `annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;` in the `mapVIEW` VIEW